# Multiple custom micro sites, how to shut them down during maintenance?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple smallish micro-sites that are all custom built, none of them is built on any common codebase (legacy).

During maintenance, when I need to bring these sites down it is a manually process setting up a custom page that it redirects to when things are getting updated during the downtime.

I want to build a common library that I can drop into each site to control things at a global level to switch sites on/off.

What would you suggest I do to do this?

Comment: Does maintenance involve updating sites themselves or is it just something like database maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

I would place a file in the root folder(wwwroot?) that these sites can look to before serving information. That file could contain a simple flag that indicates if information should be served, and possibly a url that they should redirect a user to when the sites are down.

All of this assumes you are able to modify those projects to utilize this file of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what "maintenance" means - if it is code update adding any new code will not help as you need to stop site anyway. If it is some sort of "database/back-end maintenance" adding shared code is option, also if code is not familiar to you it may be hard/dangerous to do.

More options:

- redirect at DNS level (if you can repoint DNS within acceptable time) to some special "all sites down" place
- Url rewrite at IIS level to redirect all Urls to custom site (will avoid touching existing sites)

Answer (score 0):

Add an [app_offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) file to each application.  The contents of this page will be served for any request to the site while it exists.  When you're done, remove the file.